# Convergence and closed-form expression of infinite series involving zeros of Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, laplace-transform, contour-integration, bessel-functions

Does the following infinite series converge?

\begin{align}
\label{eq:series}
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_{j}^{2} \,t},
\end{align}

where $t\in R$, $t>0$ and $\lambda_{j}$ is the j-th zero of the Bessel function of the first kind $J_{3/2}(x)$.
If it does converge, how to obtain a closed-form expression of it?

The following are what I have tried.

By using [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle), one can convert the infinite series into contour integral
on complex plane

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_{j}^{2} \,t} = \frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}} \oint_{C}\mathrm{e}^{-z^{2}\,t} \frac{J'_{3/2}(z)}{J_{3/2}(z)} \mathrm{d} z,
\end{align}

where the contour curve $C$ should be carefully chosen.
I do not know how to choose the contour curve properly so that the contour integral can be calculated explicitly.

I am also thinking about simplifying the infinite series by Laplace transform.
Denote

\begin{align}
f(t) \equiv \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_{j}^{2}\,t}.
\end{align}

The Laplace transformed form is

\begin{align}
F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \mathrm{e}^{-s\,t}\mathrm{d} t = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_{j}^{2}\,t} \mathrm{e}^{-s\,t}\mathrm{d} t = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda_{j}^{2}\,t} \mathrm{e}^{-s\,t}\mathrm{d} t = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s+\lambda_{j}^{2}}.
\end{align}

Is it legitimate to swap the integral and summation here given that $s\in \mathcal{C}$?
If it is, then by argument principle, there should be

\begin{align}
F(s) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s+\lambda_{j}^{2}} = -\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}\sqrt{s}} \frac{J'_{3/2}(\mathrm{i} \sqrt{s})}{J_{3/2}(\mathrm{i} \sqrt{s})} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{s}} \frac{I'_{3/2}(\sqrt{s})}{I_{3/2}(\sqrt{s})}.
\end{align}

But how to calculate the inverse Laplace transform

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi \mathrm{i}} \lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{\gamma-\mathrm{i}\, T}^{\gamma + \mathrm{i}\, T} \mathrm{e}^{s\,t} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{s}} \frac{I'_{3/2}(\sqrt{s})}{I_{3/2}(\sqrt{s})} \mathrm{d} s ,
\end{align}

where $\gamma$ is real and is greater than the real part of all the singularities of $F(s)$ according to [Wikipedia: inverse Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform).

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A side remark: are you aware of the relationship given in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3527919) ?

Comment: Could you tell the origin of the problem (partial differential equation ?).

Comment: No comment ? Don't forget that this site is based on dialog...

Comment: Sorry, a busy day. I am aware of the relationship, which is just the 1st order spherical Bessel function. But I failed to see how the relation help solve the question here.

Comment: The infinite series arise from solution of diffusion equation in 3D spherical confinement. For more background or motivation, please see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.11190).